# time portion from datetime value in LINQ

Tags: winforms, linq, .net-3.5

I have field which is of type DateTime.

When inserting a record, I am also providing the time into the field.

When reading that field with LINQ, it will return me the correct date but the time values has the default, `12:00:00 AM`

In the database, I have values with date and time for each record which is correct. The problem is that the time changes to default when reading/databinding with LINQ.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = IQueriableObject.Select(q => new 
         {AppointmentTime = q.AppointmentTime.Value.Date.TimeOfDay}) ;
```

What solution is there for extracting the time portion?

Comment: Can you show the Linq statement that you use?

Comment: dataGridView1.DataSource = IQueriableObject.Select(q => new {AppointmentTime = q.AppointmentTime.Value.Date.TimeOfDay}) ;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what is hurting you

`AppointmentTime = q.AppointmentTime.Value.Date.TimeOfDay`

When you do `q.AppointmentTime.Value.Date` it gets just the Date portion of the Value, by Default the `TimeOfDay` Property on a `Date` is 12:00:00 AM.

Instead you should do `q.AppointmentTime.Value.TimeOfDay` (this will only work if value is a type `DateTime`).